Adding unnumbered chapter between Abstract and Acknowledgements in thesis
I am writing my masters thesis using a university provided template (cam-thesis.cls based document), but I need to customize the preamble to include a statement of contribution. I want this to be placed between the abstract and the acknowledgements, but it always ends up before the title page or after the preamble. I have tried using \chapter*{} in the preamble and before \frontmatter in the main text, and \input{} with a separate file in the preamble.
The preamble is set up as follows:
\documentclass[rgb,listoffigures,listoftables,final]{cam-thesis}

% Document Details
\title{Thesis Title}
\author{}
\date{Nov 2024}
\thesistype{thesis proposal}
\submittedto{the thesis proposal committee}
\degree{}
\program{}
\college{}
\location{}
\submissiondate{2024}

% PDF meta-info:
\subjectline{\@title}
\keywords{keyword 1, keyword 2, etc.}

\abstract{%
    Abstract Goes Here
}

\acknowledgements{%
    Acknowledgements go here
}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}

And this is input to main.tex with:

\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter

